# No SQLlite database in directory after calling create_engine in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

After navigating to a directory and typing the commands in the Python shell:

```
 from sqlalchemy import *
 db = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db')
```

I do not see a database file called tutorial.db file in the directory. Do I have to use a different command to create the actual database file and save it?

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy's `Engine` object lazily constructs the actual underlying database connection, waiting until the first database operation before trying to connect to the database.

Try running a query or creating a table and see if the database appears.